# Unable to compile an example app using PcapPlusPlus

Tags: windows, gcc, installation, g++, pcapplusplus

I wish to learn the [PcapPlusPlus library](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/docs/install) in order to manipulate packets. I am using a Cygwin terminal on Windows 10 with all the development tools installed in Cygwin. So, i downloaded the [pcapplusplus-20.08-windows-mingw-w64-gcc-8.1.0.zip](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/releases/download/v20.08/pcapplusplus-20.08-windows-mingw-w64-gcc-8.1.0.zip) package of PcapPlusPlus from Github. Then i extracted it and went to the example-app folder. Tried building the app. To do so, I ran the following command:

```
g++.exe -I C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\header\ -I C:\cygwin64\home\home-pc\WpdPack\Include\ C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp -o C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.exe
```

Here,

- C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\header\   folder contains header files of PcapPlusPlus
- C:\cygwin64\home\home-pc\WpdPack\Include\   folder contains include header files of WinPcap needed for this tool to work.

**When i run this command i get lots of errors. I am new to using C++ libraries. What am i doing wrong here and how to fix it? My errors are as follows:**

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `pcpp::PcapFileReaderDevice::open()' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x3e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol` pcpp::PcapFileReaderDevice::open()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `pcpp::RawPacket::RawPacket()' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x66): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol` pcpp::RawPacket::RawPacket()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `pcpp::PcapFileReaderDevice::getNextPacket(pcpp::RawPacket&)' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x75): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol` pcpp::PcapFileReaderDevice::getNextPacket(pcpp::RawPacket&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `pcpp::Packet::Packet(pcpp::RawPacket*, bool, unsigned long, pcpp::OsiModelLayer)' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0xb5): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol` pcpp::Packet::Packet(pcpp::RawPacket*, bool, unsigned long, pcpp::OsiModelLayer)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to `pcpp::IPv4Address::toString() const' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x116): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol` pcpp::IPv4Address::toString() const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x135): undefined reference to `pcpp::IPv4Address::toString() const' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x135): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol` pcpp::IPv4Address::toString() const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `pcpp::IFileDevice::close()' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x177): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol` pcpp::IFileDevice::close()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x193): undefined reference to `pcpp::RawPacket::~RawPacket()' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x193): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol` pcpp::RawPacket::~RawPacket()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `pcpp::RawPacket::~RawPacket()' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text+0x1e4): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol` pcpp::RawPacket::~RawPacket()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4pcpp6PacketD1Ev[_ZN4pcpp6PacketD1Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `pcpp::Packet::destructPacketData()' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4pcpp6PacketD1Ev[_ZN4pcpp6PacketD1Ev]+0x1f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol` pcpp::Packet::destructPacketData()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceD2Ev[_ZN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceD2Ev]+0x31): undefined reference to `pcpp::IFileDevice::~IFileDevice()' /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceD2Ev[_ZN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceD2Ev]+0x31): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4pcpp20PcapFileReaderDeviceC1EPKc[_ZN4pcpp20PcapFileReaderDeviceC1EPKc]+0x1c): undefined reference to` pcpp::IFileReaderDevice::IFileReaderDevice(char const*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x28): undefined reference to `pcpp::IFileDevice::close()' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x38): undefined reference to` pcpp::IPcapDevice::setFilter(std::string)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x40): undefined reference to `pcpp::IPcapDevice::clearFilter()' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x78): undefined reference to` non-virtual thunk to pcpp::IPcapDevice::setFilter(std::string)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x80): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to pcpp::IPcapDevice::clearFilter()' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/home-pc/AppData/Local/Temp/ccW3DOf2.o:C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTVN4pcpp20PcapFileReaderDeviceE[.refptr._ZTVN4pcpp20PcapFileReaderDeviceE]+0x0): undefined reference to` vtable for pcpp::PcapFileReaderDevice'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.

Comment: Remove spaces between `-I` and include folders: `g++.exe -IC:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\header\ -IC:\cygwin64\home\home-pc\WpdPack\Include\ C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.cpp -o C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\projects\pcapplusplus\example-app\main.exe`

Comment: did that still now working

Comment: You need to specify PcapPlusPlus lib location, WinPcap lib location, as well as the lib names. Please follow the instruction in `README.release` in `pcapplusplus-20.08-windows-mingw-w64-gcc-8.1.0.zip` or take a look at `mk\PcapPlusPlus.mk`